# How to mock a feign client call in configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, spock, feign

I'm using a **spring boot** application and some **feign** clients to reach endpoints from a backend. I'm using a specific client to get a JWT token for authentication and I decided to call this client in a **configuration class** to create a **bean** from my JWT token. I'm using feign interceptor where I inject my bean token and where I fill the proper header for every http call to my backend and it's working as I expected.

The problem I'm facing now is that I would like to **mock/stub** the call to the service returning the JWT token for my tests who are kinda unit tests, but due to the fact it is in my configuration class, I don't know how I'm supposed to do. I'm using **groovy/spock** for my tests. I tried to find documentation but can't find something who really helped me.

Comment: I assume you are autowiring dependencies. You have to stop using that (it's not a great practice) and modularise your config so you can replace things as needed. This [article](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-modules/) explains this approach a bit. Or read about Google Guice modules, as it's the same principle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code? Please edit your question, converting it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so everybody can reproduce your problem. A full minimal application and a full test would help you to get the answer you are looking for. 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.